# django specified database table different from what is specified

Tags: django, django-models

In my django model I am specifying the db table i want to use with class

```py
class Meta: 
        db_table = 'users'
```

however I am getting the error

```
 django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'db.users' doesn't exist")
```

why is django adding the database name before the table name when trying to look for the table name?

I've looked in the migrations file and

```
options={
    'users',
},
```

is specified

Comment: The `db` in `db.users` refers to the app's label. Try running the migrations again.

Comment: I called the app something different its 'myServer'. It matches DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '...',
        'HOST': '...',  # or the hostname of your MySQL server
        'PORT': '3306',  # MySQL default port
    }
} I ran the migrations and nothing changed

Comment: Have you tried re-creating the database entirely (i.e. dropping the database and then running the migrations again)?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know if I understand this. What do you mean by dropping the database? Do you mean recreating the database in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the state of the database has diverged from the state described by the migrations. Here are some things you could try to fix this:

([django migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#migrate) documentation for reference)

#### Resetting migrations

1. Undo all migrations: `python manage.py migrate [app_label] zero`
2. Run migrations again: `python manage.py migrate`

This will first remove all tables created by the app's migrations, and then re-create those tables. **Keep in mind you will lose all data contained in those tables.** Undoing the migrations will fail if the migration refers to tables that do not exist in the database (which seems to be the case here).

#### Starting from scratch

1. delete the database
2. re-create the database
3. run migrations again

This is the nucular approach, but it reliably fixes most migration issues. **Obviously, this will destroy your data as well.**
Useful links: [django dbshell command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#dbshell), [django notes on MySql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#mysql-notes) and [drop database on mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-database.html).

#### Create the table yourself

You could add the missing table using SQL yourself.
But I don't recommend. Let Django take care of the database through its migrations. Only mess with the database if you know what you are doing.

Comment: I will try this, thanks!